# docompress-zip in Node WebKit app cannot unzip downloaded file, downloaded file "corrupt" according to WinRAR

Tags: ajax, node.js, zip, node-webkit, compression

I'm attempting to write an automated installer for a *.exe file. I am using node-webkit, my unzipper is decompress-zip. I am downloading the installer via AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://mywebste.com/SyncCtrl.zip',
    contentType: "application/zip;",
    success: function (dat) {
      console.log(dat)
      fs.writeFile("./SyncCtrl.zip", dat, function () {
        console.log(dat)
      })
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log(err)
      fs.writeFile("./SyncCtrl.zip", err.responseText, function () {

      })
    }
  })
```

The .zip is written through the err.responseText content. I know this isn't best practice, but I haven't been able to get it into the success callback, even though the response code is 200. This is for another question though.

After I write the .zip file to disk, I wait for an authentication request, then unzip it in the success callback:

```
var unzip = new dc("./SyncCtrl.zip")

        unzip.on('error', function (err) {
          console.log("Something went terribly wrong.")
          console.log(err)
        })

        unzip.on('extract', function (log) {
          console.log("Finished!")
          console.log(log)
        })

        unzip.on('progress', function (i, c) { //index, count (irrelevant for single file)
          console.log("Extraction progress.")
        })

        unzip.extract({
          path: "./SyncCtrl"
        })
```

This is nearly copy/pasted directly from the decompress-zip github page. This fails, in the error handler it prints:

```
Error {message: "File entry unexpectedly large: 80606 (max: 4096)"}
```

I assume this limit is in MB? This is very confusing as in both locations the file size on disk is 1.7MB for the file I'm trying to extract. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to interpret the static file as a stream.

Simply using the static file on the server, this is my working node-webkit code:

```
  var file = fs.createWriteStream("./MOCSyncCtrl.zip");
  var request = https.get("https://moc.maps-adr.com/MOCSyncCtrl.zip", function (response) {
    response.pipe(file);
  });
```